# Return implicit function in Scala

Tags: scala, implicit

I currently have this setup where I have a method and some implicit resource and the method returns a function I can use later in my code.

```
type AResource = Int

def testA(s: String)(implicit aResource: AResource): (Double) => (String, Int) = (d: Double) => {
  (s + d, d.toInt * aResource)
}

implicit val ar:AResource = 3

val fA = testA("org: ")
fA(3.1415)
```

This will print `(org: 3.1415,9)` as expected. So far so good

However sometimes I want to want to call this method in a oneliner, and this forces me to make the implicit explicit.

```
val fA2 = testA("org2: ")(ar)(1.123)
```

This seems a minor inconvenience, but the problem is actually a bit more convolutes, since my method used `TypeTag` and injects implicit typeTag into the function as well.

What I'm looking for is a way to define `testA` so that the return function implements the implicits.

like this (which obviously doesn't work)

```
def testB(s: String): (Double, AResource) => (String, Int) = (d: Double)(implicit aResource: AResource) => {
 (s + d, d.toInt * aResource)
}
```

But then I could just run

```
testB("org2: ")(1.123)
```

and worry about the implicits at the lowest level

UPDATE:

I found this solution at least, but it's not 100% perfect yet

```
def testC(s: String): (Double) => (AResource) => (String, Int) = (d: Double) => { implicit aResource: AResource => {
  (s + d, d.toInt * aResource)
}}

val c:(String, Int) = testC("org: ")(2.4)(ar)
```

It does move the implicit down the line, but I still have to pass it hardcoded.

UPDATE 2:

Tim came with a nice solution for the toy problem, but only works because the implicit resource was already in scope during the definition.

[image: No implicits found]

When the implicit is removed from scope the definition fails

Comment: Nota that in **Scala 3**, this will be fixed and your code will work as expected.

Comment: Interesting. My codebase is in Spark, though, probably not any time soon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write it as a curried function and use Eta expansion for the first usage:

```
def testC(s: String)(d: Double)(implicit aResource: AResource) =
  (s + d, d.toInt * aResource)

val fC = testC("org: ") _
fC(3.1415)

testC("33")(2.0)
```

---

**PREVIOUS INCORRECT ANSWER**

You can implement `testB` like this:

```
def testB(s: String) = {
  def f(d: Double)(implicit aResource: AResource) = (s + d, d.toInt * aResource)

  f _
}
```

You can call this both ways:

```
val fB = testB("org: ")
fB(3.1415)

testB("org2: ")(1.123)
```

This fails because the implicit resolution is done inside `testB` rather than when `f` is called.

Comment: Oh smart indeed. I'll give it a go

Comment: It works in the sample of course, but when I try to define the function outside of the scope of the defined implicit it gives an error.